# Two jquery slide ranger

Tags: javascript, jquery

First question from me! I have search for possible ways to do this function that i want but could not find anything that helped me out..

I´m new at javascript and working with this as base:
http://jsfiddle.net/danieltulp/gz5gN/42/
When i adjust the Price-slider, i want to se what price in numbers that i´m searching for.

ex. search from 123$ - 900$

And the same with quality.

I´m also trying to make each slider have different min-max and values, is that possible?

```
$(function() {
var options = {
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 250,
    step: 1,
    values: [0, 250],
    change: function(event, ui) {
        var minP = $("#price").slider("values", 0);
        var maxP = $("#price").slider("values", 1);
        var minQ = $("#quality").slider("values", 0);
        var maxQ = $("#quality").slider("values", 1);
        showProducts(minP, maxP, minQ, maxQ);
    }
};
```

Comment: The jsfiddle example simply reuses the same function. You can use two functions. All your questions can be answered by looking at the jsfiddle. What you lack is an understanding how HTML, Javascript and the DOM work. You have to learn that on your own.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#multiple-vertical

Answer (score 0):

2 functions are needed. One for each slider's `onChange` event. After each `onChange` function execution `min` and `max` values for each slider should be updated based on the calculation results. `showProducts()` will work in its current form.

This UX feels too complicated. Have you considered representing your data filtering somehow else?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it!

fiddle found here: http://jsfiddle.net/5PAa7/28/
i put it in to two variables instead of two functions.

```
function showProductsP(minP, maxP) {
$(".product-box").filter(function() {
    var price = parseInt($(this).data("price"), 10);
    if(price >= minP && price <= maxP){
         $(this).show();
    } else {
         $(this).hide();
    }
});
$(function() {
var options = {
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 900,
    step: 5,
    values: [0, 900],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        var minP = $("#slider-price").slider("values", 0);
        var maxP = $("#slider-price").slider("values", 1);
        var minL = $("#slider-length").slider("values", 0);
        var maxL = $("#slider-length").slider("values", 1);
        $(this).parent().find(".amount").html(ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ]);
        showProducts(minP, maxP, minL, maxL);
    }
};
    var options_length = {
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 60,
    step: 1,
    values: [0, 60],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        var minP = $("#slider-price").slider("values", 0);
        var maxP = $("#slider-price").slider("values", 1);
        var minL = $("#slider-length").slider("values", 0);
        var maxL = $("#slider-length").slider("values", 1);
        $(this).parent().find(".amount").html(ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ]);
        showProducts(minP, maxP, minL, maxL);
    }
};
```